# SWT, using a transparent drag image against an animated background on Windows

Tags: java, windows, image, swt, drag-and-drop

I have a custom widget based on Canvas that displays some items that the user can drag sort. When the user drags something, I am using an Image of the dragged item as the drag image:

```
final DragSource source = new DragSource(this, DND.DROP_MOVE);
source.setDragSourceEffect(new DragSourceEffect(this) {
    @Override
    public void dragStart(DragSourceEvent event) {
        event.image =   // do some stuff to generate a partially
                        // transparent image of the dragged item...
    }
});
```

This worked fine until I've implemented animating the items in the Canvas to indicate to the user how items will be rearranged if a drop were to occur. That is, it still works perfectly on all platforms (GTK, Mac) except Windows. On Windows it looks like whenever I move the mouse, the platform takes a snapshot of the current Canvas contents, composes the drag image on top and places the (non transparent) result on screen. Obviously that mechanism has horrible results when the background is actually animated and changes while the mouse doesn't move. The area where the drag image appears still displays the contents at the time of the last mouse move, while the area around the drag image is animated and updated.

The solution that comes to mind is to implement a drag image myself by manually moving a transparent, custom shaped Shell along with the mouse. Before I go and do that, is my interpretation of the problem correct, and is there perhaps a simple solution that would fix the drag image rendering against an animated background on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Redrawing during drag-over seems to be a major headache and there is a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=218823) reported also for your specific situation. So, your interpretation is correct in the sense that (on Windows?) drag over doesn't cause redraw/update of underlying control (and if you force it yourself you just get a lot of cheese).

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming the problem and sharing the pain. I have simply implemented my own DND handling. I install a global event filter for mouse move events for as long as the mouse is pressed, and use a transparent, shaped window as the drag image, which I move along with the mouse. This gave me the additional freedom to handle drag events even when the mouse is actually outside my target widget, but the "drag image" is still mostly over it at an acceptable drop location.